# Generating multiple JSON object arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I already have an array like this.

```
var dataLayer = [];
dataLayer = [{
'transactionProducts': [{
'sku': '96710381',
'name': 'QEH',
'category': 'GLD',
'price': '309.00',
'quantity': '3'
},
{
'sku': '96710382',
'name': 'RYP',
'category': 'FMT',
'price': '209.00',
'quantity': '3'
}]
}];
```

Now, I need to generate another array and with all the values in the above array. This is how I am doing it. Please find the code below. But only the first set of values get generated. The second set does not get generated in the new array. Appreciate some comments on how to get this going!

```
var length = dataLayer[0]['transactionProducts'].length;
var len = dataLayer.length;
var gtmDataLayer = [];
var gtmDataLayer = [];
for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
var zsku = window.dataLayer[0]['transactionProducts'][i].sku;
var zsku = window.dataLayer[0]['transactionProducts'][i].sku;
var zname = window.dataLayer[0]['transactionProducts'][i].name;
var zcat = window.dataLayer[0]['transactionProducts'][i].category;
var zprice = window.dataLayer[0]['transactionProducts'][i].price;
var zquant = window.dataLayer[0]['transactionProducts'][i].quantity;
window.gtmDataLayer.push({
'transactionProducts': [{
'sku': zsku,
'name': zname,
'category': zcat,
'price': zprice,
'quantity': zquant
}]
});
}
```

Comment: Your code works, you'll get the following structure as the result: `[ {transactionProducts: [{category: "GLD" etc.}]}, {transactionProducts: [{category: "FMT" etc.}]} ]`

Comment: @falsecrypt - Yes the code does work, but the code does not work with the second object array It stops once the first one is generated. However, figured this out thanks to the answer from Shadab (see below). Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
var length = dataLayer[0]["transactionProducts"].length;
var len = dataLayer.length;
var gtmDataLayer = [{"transactionProducts":[]}];

for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
    var zsku = window.dataLayer[0]["transactionProducts"][i].sku;
    var zname = window.dataLayer[0]["transactionProducts"][i].name;
    var zcat = window.dataLayer[0]["transactionProducts"][i].category;
    var zprice = window.dataLayer[0]["transactionProducts"][i].price;
    var zquant = window.dataLayer[0]["transactionProducts"][i].quantity;

    gtmDataLayer[0]['transactionProducts'].push(
        {
        "sku": zsku,
        "name": zname,
        "category": zcat,
        "price": zprice,
        "quantity": zquant
        }
    );
}
```

Later, You may also try automating the pushing of "transactionProducts" dynamically

Comment: - Thank you so much ! works like a charm. Absolutely, I am going to figure out a way to automate the push dynamically. Thanks much !